# Converting an algebraic equation into a ODE

Tags: differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

I'm working on a method to solve algebraic equations by converting them into ordinary differential equations (ODEs) and then integrating these ODEs over time.

Given an algebraic equation $f(x(t), t) = 0$, I differentiate it with respect to $t$ to obtain an ODE:
$$
\dot{x} = -\frac{f_t(x, t)}{f_x(x, t)}.
$$

Assuming a regular enough solution to the algebraic equation, I use this ODE to find the evolution of $x(t)$ over time, starting with an initial condition $x_0$ such that $f(x_0, 0) = 0$.

I'm concerned about the potential for numerical instabilities: small errors might grow over time and affect the accuracy of the solution.

1. What strategies can I employ to mitigate the risks of numerical instability when integrating this ODE?
2. Are there specific numerical methods or practices recommended for ensuring that the integration remains stable over time?
3. If small errors are introduced at the initial condition or during integration, how can one assess the sensitivity of the solution to these errors (e.g. linearization)?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds kind of like homotopy continuation, except you don't really have a stopping system.

Comment: Is your goal to solve this for large $t$? If so in the generality you describe I don't think there is any hope. Your ODE solves for the level sets of $f(x,t)$, so immediately when you start to think about the numerical instability issue, you have to ask the question "whether the level sets of $f(x,t) = \pm\epsilon$ behaves like those of $f(x,t) = 0$", and you can easily imagine the answer being very much in the negative. // Perhaps you are implicitly making some assumptions on your knowledge of the functions $f$, $f_x$ and $f_t$, it would help to spell some of them out.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "algebraic equation". I don't know if you really mean [functions that are expressible as roots of a polynomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function). If that's the case, formally introduce a variable $z$, then there exists a polynomial $P(x,t,z)$ such that $f(x,t)$ is the solution to $P(x,t,z) = 0$. And your equation reduces to itself a solution to the equation $P(x,t,0) = 0$.

There is a lot of history on solving these kinds of polynomial equations, and a lot of existing software implementations. [surf](https://surf.sourceforge.net/) (unfortunately no longer in development) was a visualizer for real algebraic surfaces and can certainly be used to draw algebraic curves.

Given this, I am wondering whether by "algebraic equation $f(x(t),t) = 0$" you are using only the words "algebraic" in contrast to "differential", and that your function $f$ can in fact contain transcendental expressions and such. Below I am *writing under this interpretation*.

---

I also assume you are well aware of obvious issues that may arise, including roots disappearing and bifurcating. Specifically I am assuming that you have some hidden assumptions on the functions $f$, $f_x$ and $f_t$ which prevent these issues.

---

**Second Disclaimer**: I am not a numerical analyst. But I do study stability of differential equations for a living.

To me, the key thing to understand about your approach is that

> The equation $\dot{x} = - \frac{f_t}{f_x}$ is not solving for $f(x(t),t) = 0$, but it is solving for $f(x(t),t) = c$ where $c$ is any constant. The constant is decided by the initial data.

This means that the stability of your algorithm is heavily influenced by how the level sets $\{f(x,t) = \pm \epsilon\}$ compare with $\{f(x,t) = 0\}$. If you have something like $f(x,t) = e^{-t^2} x$, then you see that any small numerical error will shift you from the $0$-level set to some $\epsilon$-level set, but then integration of the $\epsilon$-level set will bring a solution that, at large time $t$, that diverges from that of the $0$-level set at rate $e^{t^2}$.

You can even get something worse. Look at $f(x,t) = e^{-(x-1)^2 - t^2} - e^{-(x+1)^2 - t^2}$. It has a unique solution to $f(x(t),t) = 0$ and $f_x$ does not vanish along it. But for ever $c\in (-1/2,1/2)\setminus 0$, the $c$-level set of $f$ is a closed circle.

But such an issue can be solved, and you can also get a way to improve numerical stability out of this. The idea is this: given any non-zero function $K$, the zero set of $f$ and the zero set of $Kf$ are the same. So we can introduce an artificial weight $K$ to regularize your ODE. Let's see how this would work.

Let $K(t)$ denote an as-of-yet unspecified strictly positive function. Then applying your algorithm to $Kf$ instead of $f$, you find yourself solving

$$ \dot{x} = - \frac{K(t) f_t(x,t) + K'(t) f(x,t)}{K(t) f_x(x,t)} = - \frac{f_t(x,t)}{f_x(x,t)} - \frac{K'(t)}{K(t)} \frac{f(x,t)}{f_x(x,t)}$$

Notice that if $x(t)$ is sticking to the solution, then since $f(x,t) = 0$ the second term drops out.

But if we are slightly off, say instead of $x(t)$ we computed $x(t) + \delta$, where $\delta$ is some small error. The Taylor expanding $f(x,t)$ near the true solution $x(t)$ we get $f(x(t)+\delta,t) \approx f'(x(t),t) \delta$ and by continuity (assumed) of $f_x$ we also have $f_x(x(t)+\delta,t) \approx f_x(x(t),t)$. [Note that these last steps implicitly uses that you have knowledge that $f_x$ is continuous, non vanishing, with quantitative controls on both.]
From this we see that the equation is
$$ (x(t) + \delta)' \approx - \frac{f_t(x,t)}{f_x(x,t)} - \frac{K'(t)}{K(t)} \delta \tag{A}\label{approxeq}$$

What's important here is that if we choose $K(t)$ so that $K'(t)/K(t)$ is large, then this would provide a stabilizing feedback term to push the error back toward the correct solution (introducing a $\delta$ error gives a correction to the velocity that is $-K'/K \cdot \delta$.)

**Remark**: I deliberately omitted something from the analysis above to illustrate the point. In the actual analysis, the first term in \eqref{approxeq} should be correctly evaluated as
$$  \frac{f_t(x+\delta,t)}{f_x(x+\delta,t)} \approx \frac{f_t(x,t)}{f_x(x,t)} + \frac{f_{tx}(x,t) \delta}{f_x(x,t)} - \frac{f_t(x,t)f_{xx}(x,t) \delta}{(f_x(x,t))^2} $$
In order to fix the instability coming from the divergence of the level sets of the original $f(x,t)$, you must choose $K'(t)/K(t)$ to be large enough to eat up both of the $\delta$-terms in the previous displayed equation. To be able to choose appropriate $K$ you need to have therefore quite precise knowledge on $f$ and its first and second derivatives.